# Need a Report that shows all objects where a string field has more than 50 chars

Tags: criteria-filter

So,
I'm trying to build a report in SalesForce that will return all objects that have 50 or more characters in one designated string field.
The objects are called Items.
The field that I'm looking at is called Item Name in Store.
That field is just a string and I need to find the ones that have names 50 characters or longer.

Is there a formula I can put into the filter field?

BTW: I'm new to SalesForce... so, apologies in advance for the ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a formula of type number like this

```
LEN(text)
```

And in your report add this a filter.